New tongue drum - no musical experience whatsoever - notes map?
I just purchased a new tongue drum off eBay.  The listing title was: "BURNING&LIN Steel Tongue Drum" but under brand on the listing's details page, is: "Unbranded."  It is 15" with 14 notes, a kind of blue-grey textured metal with a light grey macramé-ish thing around its waist, It came with a white carrying bag, plus the sticks, finger thingies, more number stickers and what look like replacement feet.  It also has a songbook, but it's pretty sparse on info.  The tongues are shaped like the fat end of an Edison lightbulb, with a point at the top of each.
How can I jam with friends, when my notes are numbers instead of letters and they're like - play me a D or an F or whatever, and I'm like, what number is that?  (embarrassing)  How can I figure out what actual notes these tongues are?  It's frustrating, but I'm in love with the drum!
I have looked on this site and on the interwebs in general, but everyone is talking in music terms that I don't understand - for example:  pentatonic?  I thought that was an acapella singing group?  I really didn't want to have to take music lessons or learn music theory, just to have fun.  I found some info here and elsewhere, but it doesn't seem to line up with reality, so I'm stuck with numbers.  I really want to put letter stickers on it until I can play it without needing to look so hard or test out different tongues.  Anyone know where can I get a map?
This is the ebay listing:  BURNING&LIN Steel Tongue Drum
Thank you in advance!  :o)
~Dawn.

One simple trial-and-error way: when your friend says "Play me a D," say "you play me one!", and then try your pitches to find one that matches.

Note: the proposed duplicate is too specific to its model to be useful here. Voting against duplicate.

@AndyBonner but the notation is the same for both.

@Tom Yes, but the question was not "how do I read [what this ebay listing refers to as] 'standard' numeric labels for tongue drums." The question asserted that the instrument was pentatonic and the answer restricts itself to that, giving a map for each of its keys. The current OP seems to have a full diatonic set, and lacks the musical experience to extrapolate from the pentatonic answer.

@AndyBonner Fair point, but the op also asks for a "map" of the notes which the dup does give. Well, best would be to know if the op is satisfied with the dup :)

It appears to have 15 tongues,(you reckon 14?) with numbers ranging from 1-7. That presumes there are two octaves, with say, 1 and 1, 2 and 2 being octave copies of each other, and the notes belonging to one specific diatonic scale.
I guess that no. 1 will be the tonic, or root note. By playing sequentially, you should hear a complete octave up to the next tongue 1. All you need to do then is match tongue no.1 with a note on say, piano, that will reveal which key the drum is tuned to.
IF... note 1 is C, then each number represents a single letter. If it's G, for example, note 7 will be F♯. Sorry, there has to be a modicum of theory to all this...
That's the key you'll be able to get your friends to play in for you to play along.

I have a very similar (but smaller) tongue drum in C. The numbers on yours go from 1 to 7, so I'd expect a diatonic scale like mine. That's the "white keys," not a pentatonic scale, which is the "black keys," nor a chromatic scale, which is both.
Most likely 1 is C, 2 is D, and so on up to 7=B. You can confirm this with a tuner like this one (inevitably they'll be out of tune, but don't worry about it). Whatever note corresponds to 1 is the key of your drum, e.g. C Major.
You'll only be able to play music strictly in that key and its modes. Hopefully you can rely on your friends' theory knowledge to make appropriate selections and transpose them into a useful key, but accidentals (which you can't play) are very common, so be patient.

PiedPiper deleted their answer, so you might edit to elaborate on the most helpful bit of advice so far, "check the pitches with a tuner"

@AndyBonner Noted and substantially edited, thanks.

If indeed it is diatonic in whatever key, none of the parallel modes will be available. Parallels use the same tonic, but then different notes. Think simple parallel major/minor. -1.

@Tim You're right, what's the term I'm thinking of? Blanking.

''Strictly in that parent key and its modes'?

@AndyBonner That information is already in the answers to the duplicate.
